# How to make a bash function persist (after reboot)?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

The command is

```
Show() { cat /etc/redhat-release; }
```

How to make this command persist after reboot?

Comment: As you can see from the current answers, we are unsure what you mean by "persist".  You question was also originally tagged with `ssh` (I removed that tag).  Please let us know if `ssh` is somehow relevant to you question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that by "make this command persist" you mean "make it still be defined after a reboot".

Comment: Look at `declare -f Show` and make a `SaveFunc` helper to save the functions giving by their name into e.g. the `~/.bash_funcs.d` directory. Then add some white magic to `bash`'s startup scripts to read in all functions defined in that directory.

Answer (score 6):

To make a function definition persist after reboot, you do same thing as you would do to add or modify persistent shell aliases and/or environment variables: You edit your shell initialization files.

If you add your function definition in `~/.bashrc` (or wherever you usually define aliases), it will be available for use in the next interactive `bash` shell session.